# Division creates megafile in R

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I have a DataFrame in R:

```
             Category1            Category 2      x              y  x.x
1                     T                    A      1              9    9
2                     T                    B      2              8    9
3                     T                    A     10              7    9
4                     T                    C     19              6    9
                      z            a    x.y          x.y   x.y
1            0.11111111            1   2342 0.0004269855 0.000
2            0.22222222            3   2342 0.0012809564 0.001
3            0.33333333           13   2342 0.0055508113 0.006
4            0.44444444           32   2342 0.0136635354 0.014
```

The last two columns - for some reason - do not show the name I gave them (say `x.1` and `x.2`) but instead always show the third to last column name. Column `x.1` is the result of division of `a/x.y`, `x.2` is the same thing just rounded. Now, having created this `data.frame` (with about `4,000 rows`) I create a simple csv:

```
write.csv(DF, 'DF.csv')
```

This - strangely - produces a **34 GB** file. When I leave out the last two columns it becomes a tiny file of `2MB`. How can I avoid this huge file, where does it come from?

EDIT

---

division operation:

```
DF$x.1 <- DF$a/DF['x.y']
```

data loading:

```
DF <- read.csv('data.csv', sep=';')
```

Comment: Hi Arun, I edited a few things, however, I cannot paste the CSV as the content is confidential. It shouldn't matter however, since, when I use write.csv on all columns except the last one it works. This one division seems to produce a huge column - but I don't know why.

Comment: It matters very much, because without a way to reproduce this behavior on our machines we have no way to investigate what could be happening.

Comment: @oliver13 To start I would do something like  `DF$x.1 <- DF$a/DF$x.y` to get  x.1 as column name.

Comment: At the _very_ least you could share `str(DF)`.

Comment: For some reason I used what agstudy suggested (DF$x.1 <- DF$a/DF$x.y) and it worked. Now the file has a normal size... not sure what happened there.

Comment: `DF['x.y']` is NOT a vector. It is a list.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid syntax error, I think that `transform` is very suitable here. Using it , you can  create new columns based on existing columns with a clean syntax.

```
transform(DF,x.1 = a/x.y,x.2 = round(a/x.y,3))
  Category1 Category X2  x y x.x         z  a  x.y          x.1   x.2
1         1     TRUE  A  1 9   9 0.1111111  1 2342 0.0004269855 0.000
2         2     TRUE  B  2 8   9 0.2222222  3 2342 0.0012809564 0.001
3         3     TRUE  A 10 7   9 0.3333333 13 2342 0.0055508113 0.006
4         4     TRUE  C 19 6   9 0.4444444 32 2342 0.0136635354 0.014
```